# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS with pretty urls?

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, https, friendly-url

I would like to redirect users entering my Webfaction hosted Wordpress site from HTTP to HTTPS and in the same time support pretty URLS. How to achieve this? I already tried few resolutions but it doesn't work. (Examples below)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#This is first attempt
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L] #Tested here some flags, no success

#This is second attempt
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=ps:https]

#This is third attempt
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^([0-9]+s)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=ps:https]

#This is fourth try
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
#SSLOptions +StrictRequire
#SSLRequireSSL
#SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "example.com"

#This is fifth attempt
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# This is Wordpress pretty URLS (Has to stay!)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

All I got was loop of redirects (301 or 302) or a page with 'Found here' where 'here' was an anchor to my domain :/
Forgot to mention, I can edit only .htaccess.

Comment: Why you dont use a plugin for that? There enough out there.
For example [ForceSSL](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/)

Comment: @0x4Dark That plugin is unnecessary piece of code I want to ommit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer https://serverfault.com/a/678402/102060 which helped me. 
It turned out that Webfaction uses some kind of loadbalancer which does not reveal itself by sending specific headers.
I tried this blind folded and it works!

```
### Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```